# Apache Camel "CronScheduledRoutePolicy" - route is not active if the server is restarted between start time and stop time

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel "CronScheduledRoutePolicy" to have my route (for jms queue) to be active between certain hours.

```
CronScheduledRoutePolicy policy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
policy.setRouteStartTime("0 0 9 * * ?");
policy.setRouteStopTime("0 0 18 * * ?");
from("jms:inboundqueue").routePolicy(policy).noAutoStartup()
....
```

It works fine as expected by starting the route at 9am and stopping it at 6pm, but if the server is restarted between these hours, the route is not active. 
is there a way to check if the route should be active during server start up ?

Comment: You need to configure how quartz should handle misfire, you can tell it to trigger asap instead